# A method returning set of object , want to store as List of string

Tags: java

I have two classes, `Student` and `Book`.
I want to store book name returned by `student.getBook(that will return Set<Book>)` into `List<String>`.

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String bookName;
    //Setter and getter.......
}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String student Name;
    private Set<Book> books;
    //Setters and Getters
}
```

Here is main method

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    Book b1= new Book(1, "art");
    Book b2= new Book(2, "science");
    Book b3= new Book(3, "bio");
    Set<Book> b=new HashSet<>();
    b.add(b1);
    b.add(b2);
    b.add(b3);
    Student s=new Student (1, "std1",b);
    //here I want to store bookName 
    //into List, some thing like
    List<String> book=new   
    ArrayList<>(s.getBooks().getBookName());
}
```

Please help.....

Comment: You have a set (i.e. a collection) of books. You want another collection of book names. So you need to create an empty list of strings, loop over all the books in the set of books, get the name of each book, and add it to the list. Of course, there are shorter ways to do that, using streams for example, but that what happens behind the scenes, and you need to do that by yourself at least once before learning streams.

Comment: Also don't you think the first model should be Book.java and not Student.java? and `private String student Name;` is strange!

Comment: Collection<Book> is common parent to Set and List. Maybe conversion You want, are tottalyy not reired

Answer (score 1):

This is where the Stream API comes in handy!

To turn a set of books (`s.getBooks()`) directly into a `List<String>` with book names, you just need to `map` and `collect`.

```
List<String> bookNames = s.getBooks().stream()
    .map(x -> x.getBookName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This might look new to you, so I'll explain it bit by bit.

The `stream` method creates a `Stream<Book>`. This is so that you can do cool operations, like `map`, `reduce` and `filter` on the `Set`. Then we `map` the stream of books. `map` is just another word for "transform". Because you only want the book names, we transform each book in the stream into its book name. The `x -> x.getBookName()` describes how we want to transform it. It means "given a book `x`, we get the book name of `x`". And finally, we call `collect`, which "collects" everything in the stream and puts them back in a collection. In this case we want a `List` so we call `toList()`.

Comment: @user8189926 If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

Since `s.getBookNames()` returns the `Set<Book>`, you must iterate over the collection to fetch individual book's name and then save it to another List in your code named as `book` :

```
List<String> bookNames = new ArrayList<>(); // initialize a list for all the book names
s.getBooks().forEach(book -> bookNames.add(book.getBookName())); // iterate all the books and add their names to the above list
```

---

Also, this assumed few obvious things as pointed in comments as well,

```
private String student Name; // this variable either named as 'student or `name` or `studentName`
```

and the first model is for the `Book.java` instead of `Student.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Someway, I see your modal definition for student is not good. Simply you can define Student modal as follow.

And create a separate public method in Student class to fetch the booknames.

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Book> books;

    public Student(int id, String name, Set<Book> b) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.books = b;
    }
// all getter and setter.

 public List<String> getBookNames(){
     return this.getBooks().stream().map(x -> x.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
}
```

if you are using java1.8, as sweeper suggested you can use stream api to do your work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book b1 = new Book(1, "art");
    Book b2 = new Book(2, "science");
    Book b3 = new Book(3, "bio");
    Set<Book> b = new HashSet<>();
    b.add(b1);
    b.add(b2);
    b.add(b3);
    Student s = new Student(1, "std1", b);
    List<String> books = s.getBookNames();
    System.out.println(books);
}
```